# How to tag multiple resources reading lazily them from an attribute?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, aws-sdk, cookbook, recipe

I want to tag multiple AWS Instances, the instance-ID for them is stored in an attribute, e.g. -

```
aws
  |_ instances
            |____ 0: i-12sdfddf
            |____ 1: i-23fdgfdg
            |____ 2: i-34rtetio
```

Here, when reading the node data, I have to lazily load the same. Following works fine for me -

```
    aws_resource_tag 'tag_instances' do
        resource_id lazy{node['aws']['instances'][0]}
        tags (tag)
    end

    aws_resource_tag 'tag_instances' do
        resource_id lazy{node['aws']['instances'][1]}
        tags (tag)
    end
.. and so on
```

But I want to tag all instances in a loop. Something like this -

```
aws_resource_tag 'tag_instances' do
  resource_id lazy {node['aws']['instances'].values}
  tags (tag)
end
```

I am new to all of this, please help.

**Update:**

As per [@seshadri_c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13968097/seshadri-c) 's answer, there is an existing bug here - [bug#243](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/aws/issues/243).

Is there a workaround for this? Something like this would help -

```
instance_values = lazy {node['aws']['instances']}

instance_values.each do |index, instance_id|
  aws_resource_tag 'ec2_instances' do
    resource_id instance_id
    tags(tags)
  end
end
```

Comment: The example attributes and individual `resource_id` shows `[aws][instance]`, but you want to loop on `['ebs']['volumes']`? Can you update the question with an example of that attribute?

Comment: Thanks, @seshadri_c .. updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `resource_id` property of `aws_resource_tag` resource can take an array of instances. So we can just take the `values` out of the `node['aws']['instances']` hash.

```rb
aws_resource_tag 'tag_instances' do
  resource_id lazy { node['aws']['instances'].values }
  tags (tag)
end
```

**Update:**

I think we are running into a [bug](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/aws/issues/243) in upstream code. It's been open for more than 3 years now.

But a typical way to loop through a Hash or Array is to use the `.each` iterator. If you can get the `node['aws']['instances']` *without* `lazy`, then you can use something like below:

```rb
node['aws']['instances'].each do |indx, instance_id|
  aws_resource_tag 'ec2_instances' do
    resource_id instance_id
    tags(tags)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is giving me error - `ArgumentError: expected params[:filters][0][:values][0] to be a String, got value ["i-12sdfddf", "i-23fdgfdg"] (class: Array) instead.`

Comment: I think we are hitting a [bug](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/aws/issues/243). I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot use `node['aws']['instances']` without `lazy` because that value is being set later in the recipe. Is there a workaround for this? something like -

`values = lazy { node['aws']['instances'] }

values.each do |indx, instance_id|
  aws_resource_tag 'ec2_instances' do
    resource_id instance_id
    tags(tags)
  end
end
`

Comment: I don't think that's possible. `lazy` won't work for variable assignment. It *only* works inside Chef resources.

Comment: Can you update the question with an example of how `node['aws']['instances']` is set in recipe?